# Flask Ajax Call, No Error, but no Response Received Back

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am using Flask and have an Ajax call to a view which finds some data within a coordinates range and I just want to be able to return that data. It is successfully reaching the view, querying the database and returning data, but no response is received at JavaScript code.

The Ajax call is like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "application/json",
      url: "/getsignswithin",
      data: dataToSubmit,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

The Flask route is like this:

```
@app.route("/getsignswithin", methods=['POST'])
def signs_within():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)

    signs = db.signs.find({
      'location': {
         '$geoWithin': {
            '$box': [
              [ data['extent'][0],data['extent'][1] ],
              [ data['extent'][2],data['extent'][3] ]
            ]
         }
      }
    })
    print(dumps(list(signs)))
    #return jsonify(success=True)
    return dumps(list(signs)), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

The print(dumps(list(signs))) shows the data, but nothing is received in the success part of the Ajax. No errors are reported to the browser console or the Python console.

I have tried with return jsonify(success=True), just to see if it returns anything, but that doesn't work either.

Console Output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:06:12] "POST /getsignswithin HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[<listdatahere>]
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2020 17:06:13] "POST /getsignswithin HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Are you sure the ajax call is what's posting to the view? It seems to be making a request to `"/ratesign"` but the view handles `"/getsignswithin"`.

Comment: Hi, sorry, that was a spelling error, it is and was posting to /getsignswithin. I will update the post with the console output and change the url.

Comment: Do you call the 'POST' method within a `form` scope or outside a `form`? Try to have the error callback as well, just to see if you get any hints in there `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);  }`

Comment: With the error added to the AJAX it is giving "Error: No conversion from text to application/json"

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it like this:

```
json.dumps({'data': list(signs)}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the data is from MongoDB, I am using bson.json_util.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the datatype to just "json", not "application/json" enables it to return the data. Thanks newbie99 for the advice on the error callback which enabled me to identify the issue. I will remember to do that in my future troubleshooting.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/getsignswithin",
      data: dataToSubmit,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```